# Using LAG function inside UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have the following table, where I need to update the [QuotaReached] column accordingly:

[SalesTable]

[image: 1]

For SalesTable, I need to apply this rule (will write as pseudo code):
IF Staff_Id_Sales > 3000 AND QuotaReached for PREVIOUS [date] = 1 THEN 2.

**Explanation:** QuotaReached = 2 for Staff_Id 5 in the last row, since:

a) there is > 3000 in sales on the last row's date.

b) The previous row for Staff_Id 5 had QuotaReached = 1. "Previous row" thus refers to the row with the most recent previous date (i.e the second last row containing the date 2002-25-04).

My thoughts/attempts: I believe I need to use the LAG() function, but when I try to throw a LAG() function in a CASE WHEN statement, it fails (since its a windowed function, which requires a select or order by clause).

I need to apply more business rules than this, so I believe it must be inside a CASE when statement like so:

```
UPDATE SalesTable 
SET QuotaReached = (CASE WHEN Staff_Id_Sales < 5000 AND ClosedSale = 0 THEN 0
WHEN Staff_Id_Sales > 5000 AND ClosedSale = 1 OR ClosedSale THEN 3
WHEN Staff_Id_Sales < 5000 AND ClosedSale = 1 THEN 1
WHEN [a bunch of other rules apply here]
WHEN Staff_Id_Sales > 3000 AND QuotaReached for PREVIOUS [date] = 1 THEN 2. <-- the ONLY business rule,
which I need help with applying inside this update statement.
```

Is it possible to apply this in my UPDATE statement along with the other rules? If so, how? Other methods of updating the table with the needed rules are also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use cte :

```
;with cte as (
SELECT
    STAFF_ID -- or whatever the primary key is 
    , LAG(QuotaReached) OVER (partition by STAFF_ID ORDER by [date]) as Previous_QuotaReached
FROM SalesTable
)

UPDATE s 
SET QuotaReached = CASE ...
WHEN Staff_Id_Sales > 3000 AND c.Previous_QuotaReached = 1 THEN 2
FROM SalesTable s
JOIN cte c
 ON s.STAFF_ID = c.STAFF_ID
```

Comment: Removed my answer in favor of this one.